# User click on cell, prompts user to locate text file. Cell value contains path to file location

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

I have a text data file that I download to a location on my computer. Right now, in my VBA script, I have the path hard coded. What I would want, if this is possible is for the user to click a cell (C5) in worksheet "Main" in this case and when he/she does, a dialogue pops up to prompt user to navigate to the text file and select it. After the user selects the text file, I want the cell C5 value to hold the file path of the text file.

I would like the value of C5 to be substituted in for the hardcoded file path that I have in my VBA script:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;\\psf\Home\Desktop\Temp\sample.txt", Destination:=Range( _
        "$A$1"))
        .Name = "fills"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
```

I want the value of C5 to go into the part after Connection:= part which I do not know how to do as of yet and would like help/input as well.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 3):

The code below will run when a user ***right clicks*** `C5`

*Part 1*

- Right click your sheet tab
- *View Code*
- Copy and past in the code below

*code*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim strFileToOpen As String
If Target.Address(0, 0) <> "C5" Then Exit Sub

strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a file to place in C5 (pick Open)", _
FileFilter:="Text Files *.txt (*.txt),"

If strFileToOpen = "False" Then
    [c5].Value2 = "No file selected"
Else
    [c5].Value2 = strFileToOpen
End If
End Sub
```

*Part 2*

change

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;\\psf\Home\Desktop\Temp\sample.txt", Destination:=Range( _
        "$A$1"))
```

to

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & [c5].value2 & "", Destination:=Range( _
        "$A$1"))
```

Comment: Works well. Just be prepared to handle the case where the user clicks `Cancel` on the file open dialogue box.